# Did Samuel sleep in the Holy of Holies as a child?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle

I Samuel 3:3, Samuel is lying down in the presence of the lamp and the ark. But I thought the Holy of Holies was only for 1 day a year accessible, and then only for the high priest. Was the temple at Shiloh the same as the design God had given to Moses? Did Samuel sleep in the Holy of Holies? Or was he resting in God's presence so to speak rather than bedding down there? 
I know that is a lot of Questions.....

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Consider registering your account to best utilise all of the site's features.

Comment: Consider clarifying the essence of the question. At he moment it appears that several questions are being asked, and an answer might address some but not all of them, and not answer your main question. It is therefore best to clarify the crux of the question.

Comment: See the Malbim, the question is addressed there in black and white

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi, assuming that the OP doesn't have access to a Malbim, either because of language or database access, it might make more sense for you to answer with this Malbim

Answer (score 1):

As @TrustMeI'mARabbi mentions the Malbim does address this and notes that it isnt literal that he slept in the heichal since that is impossible. Rather the passuk should read that he slept somewherre else (shocehv is meant to be parenthetical). In fact Masheches Kidushin 78b deals with this passuk and explains that he slept elsewhere,passuk is talking about 2 diff places,see Rashi there which explains it well. He slept in the place of Levi,since only the kings of David were alowwed in makom hamikdash mamash.

Text of the Malbim:

[image]

Text of Rashi (Kidushim 78b):

ושמואל שוכב בהיכל ה' - חדא מילתא משמע ועל כרחך מפסקינן ליה ושמואל שוכב במקומו בבית משמר הלויים שהיו שומרים את הבית וכן תרגם יונתן בעזרת ליואי והיכל אנר קאי שהמנורה היתה בהיכל משכן שילה: